# NTFS permision via powershell

Tags: powershell, permissions, ntfs

I try to set NTFS permissions for domainlocal groups via powershell.
therefore, I followed this tutorial:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730951.aspx

I adapt that code to create the code snippet below:

```powershell
function set_NTFS_permissions ($group,$folder){
    $rule = "" # Just to make sure its empty
    $user_read = "gfo\"+$group+"_read"
    #$read_permissions = @("ReadAndExecute","Synchronize")
    $read_permissions = "ReadAndExecute,Synchronize"
    $user_write = "gfo\"+$group+"_edit"
    $write_permissions = "DeleteSubdirectoriesAndFiles,Write,ReadAndExecute,Synchronize"
    $acl = get-acl $folder # Calls for current permissions
    $acl.SetAccessRuleProtection($True,$True) # Protects inherit permissions (superior | inferior)
    $rule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($user_read,$read_permissions,'ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit','None','Allow')
    $acl.AddAccessRule($rule)
    Set-Acl $folder $acl
    $rule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($user_write,$write_permissions,'ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit','None','Allow')
    $acl.AddAccessRule($rule)
    Set-Acl $folder $acl
}

$folder = '\\domain.local\path\path\path'
$group = 'DL_fs_path'
set_NTFS_permissions $group $folder
Get-Acl $folder  | Format-List
```

This one works just fine.

My problem starts, when I use that function in another funtion.
There, I create several folders and groups (which works) and then I want to permit the groups to the folders.
To do this, I call the above funktion with some variables (which are transfered correctly ... Write-host them just before passing them to the function and then again at the beginning of the function.)

```powershell
Ausnahme beim Aufrufen von "AddAccessRule" mit 1 Argument(en):  "Some or all identity references could not be translated."
In C:\Scripts\filestruct.ps1:20 Zeichen:5
+     $acl.AddAccessRule($rule)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : IdentityNotMappedException
```

Has anyone an idea, why it works when statics are passed, but not with variables?

Comment: What are you passing to this function from the other function? Are the groups ADGroup objects? Strings objects that is just the group name? Are the folders being passed Strings or DirectoryInfo objects? Write-Host will sometimes make some assumptions with properties that other things will not if the object isn't a simple string.